# Traverse and Print Complex List

Tags: c#, .net

**Method Signature:**

```
public static string TraverseList(string prefix, object list)
```

**Input:**

```
prefix: "Boo"
list: new object[] { "a string", new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, "spam", new[] { "eggs" }, new[] { new[] { "one", "two" }, new[] { "three", "four" } } }
```

**Expected Output:**

```
Boo.0: a string
Boo.1.0: a
Boo.1.1: b
Boo.1.2: c
Boo.2: spam
Boo.3.0: eggs
Boo.4.0.0: one
Boo.4.0.1: two
Boo.4.1.0: three
Boo.4.1.1: four
```

My attempt at implementing this:

```
public static string TraverseList(string prefix, object list)
{
    int index = 0;
    int index1 = 0;
    int index2 = 0;

    StringBuilder dumpListBuilder = new StringBuilder();

    if (list is Array)
    {
        foreach (var obj in (Array)list)
        {
            if (obj is Array)
            {
                foreach (var obj1 in (Array)obj)
                {
                    if (obj1 is Array)
                    {
                        foreach (var obj2 in (Array)obj1)
                        {
                            dumpListBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}.{2}.{3}: {4}{5}", prefix, index, index1, index2, obj2, Environment.NewLine);
                            index2++;
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dumpListBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}.{2}: {3}{4}", prefix, index, index1, obj1, Environment.NewLine);
                    }
                    index1++;
                    index2 = 0;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                dumpListBuilder.AppendFormat("{0}.{1}: {2}{3}", prefix, index, obj, Environment.NewLine);
            }
            index++;
            index1 = 0;
        }
    }

    return dumpListBuilder.ToString();
}
```

It works, but isn't efficient and is limited to a depth of 3 nested lists. Can anyone suggest an optimal solution for infinite depth?

*I am aware that I should be using recursion, but how do I do that without changing the method signature?*

Comment: hint: recursion

Comment: You can't change the original dumplist signature, but you can create a further method you can call from DumpList and recursively from itself, ain't it?

Comment: @Gian Paolo There is no need for any further method

Comment: right @SirRufo, I didn't notice that you can handle the prefix changing it at each level of recursion

Comment: [This question is being discussed on meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/367813/edit-the-question-to-remove-all-its-content-after-receiving-an-answer).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could probably make it more readable, and more logical using `recursion`

**Mine**

```
public static string DumpList(string prefix, object list)
{
    if (list is object[] array)
        return String.Join("\r\n", array.Select((value, i) => DumpList($"{prefix}.{i}", value)));
    return $"{prefix}: {list}";
}
```

**MineOriginal**

```
public static void DumpList2(string prefix, object input, List<string> result)
{
   if (input is object[] ary)
      for (var i = 0; i < ary.Length; i++)
         if (ary[i] is Array)
            DumpList2($"{prefix}.{i}", ary[i], result);
         else
            result.Add($"{prefix}.{i}.{ary[i]}");
   else
      result.Add($"{prefix}.0.{input}");
}
```

## Benchmarks

```
Mode            : Release
Test Framework  : .NET Framework 4.7.1
Benchmarks runs : 100 times (averaged)

Scale : 100
Name         |     Time |    Range | StdDev |    Cycles | Pass
-----------------------------------------------------------------
MineOriginal | 0.550 ms | 0.311 ms |   0.15 | 1,853,187 | Yes
Original     | 0.612 ms | 0.361 ms |   0.13 | 2,059,844 | Base
Mine         | 0.697 ms | 0.012 ms |   0.08 | 2,368,041 | Yes
SirRufo      | 0.776 ms | 0.022 ms |   0.15 | 2,635,368 | Yes
Jimi         | 0.821 ms | 0.012 ms |   0.21 | 2,779,449 | Yes
JimiNoFormat | 0.873 ms | 0.007 ms |   0.23 | 2,950,638 | Yes


Scale : 1,000
Name         |     Time |    Range | StdDev |     Cycles | Pass
------------------------------------------------------------------
MineOriginal | 4.461 ms | 0.541 ms |   0.21 | 15,185,195 | Yes
Original     | 5.914 ms | 0.346 ms |   1.15 | 20,015,882 | Base
Mine         | 6.725 ms | 0.153 ms |   0.31 | 22,890,735 | Yes
JimiNoFormat | 6.818 ms | 0.335 ms |   0.23 | 23,193,642 | Yes
Jimi         | 6.873 ms | 0.633 ms |   0.37 | 23,382,543 | Yes
SirRufo      | 7.198 ms | 1.004 ms |   0.70 | 24,512,923 | Yes


Scale : 10,000
Name         |      Time |    Range | StdDev |      Cycles | Pass
--------------------------------------------------------------------
Original     | 57.283 ms | 3.049 ms |   5.70 | 194,331,610 | Base
MineOriginal | 67.833 ms | 5.618 ms |   2.66 | 230,951,862 | Yes
Mine         | 72.695 ms | 2.624 ms |   3.39 | 246,760,230 | Yes
Jimi         | 73.571 ms | 4.007 ms |   2.00 | 249,736,001 | Yes
JimiNoFormat | 73.659 ms | 2.204 ms |   2.92 | 249,493,594 | Yes
SirRufo      | 74.141 ms | 2.395 ms |   2.64 | 251,712,472 | Yes
```

**Remarks**

JimiNoFormat is just a version using his code with string interpolation

Scale is basically the original array joined and merged that many times, to make a super duper sized array to test

MineOriginal basically just uses a list, and converts it to string right at the end, its kind of more efficient then using a string throughout , however it doesn't scale well and eventually will lose for extremely large datasets

**Summary**

The recursion ads more overhead, buts its not too bad

Comment: @GiladReich hahah, i was thinking about it

Comment: Haha...I just came to do that too :P

Comment: Can you benchmark what I just posted? It gives me 25ms over 100 rounds, but of course it might depend on the hardware.

Comment: @Jimi sure can!

Comment: Well, that's interesting. The null checking has almost no overhead and the `for/foreach` loop is still faster than a simple, non cached, Linq `Select`. I'll take a look at the IL. Maybe this can be done using `StringBuilder` and a cached Linq extension. So, you're the official benchmark guy. Good to know too :)

Comment: @Jimi i was surprised by it as well... Yeah i wrote my own bench marking lib i use at work, its fun to pull it out and take it for a spin, it does a lot to make each test run pristine in regards to gc, also verifies the results, im getting charts hooked up soon and will chuck it on github

Comment: With charts, you say. What repository would that fall in? You know, these measures are quite important. I think there should be a SO section dedicated to benchmaking code samples over time (yes, I'm the newbie with great vision :). Btw, I forgot your more than deserved +1.

Comment: @TheGeneral - your solution under mine is brilliant! Very elegant. Well done!

Comment: @c0D3l0g1c glad to be of assistance :)

Answer (score 8):

Recursion is the key here

```
static void Main( string[] args )
{
    var prefix = "Foo";
    var input = new object[] { "a string", new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, "spam", new[] { "eggs" }, new[] { new[] { "one", "two" }, new[] { "three", "four" } } };
    var output = DumpList( prefix, input );
    Console.WriteLine( output );
}

static string DumpList( string prefix, object list )
{
    var collection = !( list is string )
        ? list as IEnumerable
        : null;
    return collection != null
        ? string.Join(
            separator: Environment.NewLine,
            values: collection.Cast<object>().Select( ( o, i ) => DumpList( $"{prefix}.{i}", o ) ) )
        : $"{prefix}: {list}";
}
```

[.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/1XYtFc)

Comment: You don't need to use negated conditions, because you handle both cases. Negations is so difficult to read brrr... ;)

Answer (score 1):

**`[For benchmarking purposes]`**
Elaboration, without null checking, of the procedure @Sir Rufo coded:
(`.NET Framework 4.7.1 - C# 7.3`)

```
var prefix = "Foo";
var input = new object[] { "a string", new[] { "a", "b", "c" }, "spam", new[] { "eggs" }, new[] { new[] { "one", "two" }, new[] { "three", "four" } } };

string output = DumpList(prefix, input);
Console.WriteLine(output);


static string DumpList(string prefix, object list) => (list is string)
                       ? $"{prefix}: {list}"
                       : string.Join(Environment.NewLine,
                                   ((IEnumerable)list).Cast<object>().Select((obj, idx) =>
                                     DumpList($"{prefix}.{idx}", obj)));
```